# Ошибка 9009 ,помогите решить

Tags: c#, .net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

signtool sign /v /f "$(SolutionDir)ThirdParty\AMC Bridge LLX.pfx" /p "AmCBridGe2018" /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /d "$(ProjectName)" /v "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"

что то неправильно в этих одинаковых строках

Comment: Судя по ответам к вопросу - [What does “exited with code 9009” mean during this build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1351830/2881286) - проблема в том, что по указанным путям отсутствуют файлы

Comment: ну в этой папке есть указанный фаил

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть другие ответы :-)